# Update many statics files in many pod in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

What is best practice for update many statics files (css, js, images) in many pod in kubernetes?

Now git-sync run every times and sync statics files (css, js, images) from git repository.

Git repository sometimes update, delete, create new statics files (css, js, images).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, you can use [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/).

> A *PersistentVolume* (PV) is a piece of storage in the cluster that has been provisioned by an administrator or dynamically provisioned using [Storage Classes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/). It is a resource in the cluster just like a node is a cluster resource. PVs are volume plugins like Volumes, but have a lifecycle independent of any individual Pod that uses the PV. This API object captures the details of the implementation of the storage, be that NFS, iSCSI, or a cloud-provider-specific storage system.

Kubernetes also supports [Volume Snapshots](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/). You can easy [backup and restore](https://www.fairwinds.com/blog/gemini-automate-backups-of-persistentvolumes-in-kubernetes) your persistent volume.

See also [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@xcoulon/storing-data-into-persistent-volumes-on-kubernetes-fb155da16666) - it shows how to store data into Persistent Volumes.